# How can I keep the force even on this RigidyBody2D during a touch event?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want the force applied to this object to be exactly the same on every touch/spacebar press, but it seems to vary wildly (even more on touches than on spacebar presses).

All I can imagine is that somehow it's applying additional force if the touch/keypress lasts through multiple update cycles. If that's true, how do I stop this issue?

Edit: jumpForce is a class-level int set to 250.

```
void Update () {

    int Touches = Input.touchCount;

    if (Input.GetKeyUp("space")) {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpForce);
    }

    if (Touches > 0) {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpForce);
    }

    Vector2 screenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    if(screenPosition.y > Screen.height || screenPosition.y < 0) {
        Die();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For running the code for the touch case only once you can use `TouchPhase.Began`:

```
if (Touches > 0) {
    if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpForce);    
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this fixes your problem however, since the `Input.GetKeyUp("space")` for example is only called once already and you say you are having issues with that as well.

Comment: Well, the issues with space are much less pronounced. I'll give this a try when I'm home this evening and accept your answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can put touchCount directly in your if statement:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
```

Also the spacebar input is probably better read on key pressed instead of on key released:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {
```

I dont know if this will fix the problem you are having, but its worth a shot.

Comment: That's likely a better way to format the code but I don't think that will effect the issue in any way.

Comment: Yes I agree. Probably should have made that a comment instead of an answer actually. Oh and the GetKeyDown vs GetKeyUp is really a situational thing, they will give a sublty different result for the player. You can also use them both with a boolean to read a "key held down" style input.